# replace html5 upload function with hardcoded path

Tags: javascript, php, html, csv

I'm trying to use a script to display a `.csv` file and make content filter and searchable.
I found [this script on github](https://github.com/kentgeorgeson/csv):

I want to put this script on my webserver (apache).
That works great, however, I want it to work with 1 or more `.csv` files that resides on the same folder.

My goal is that when the index.html is loaded, it directly displays (and handles) a `.csv` file from a path that is hardcoded in the `index.html.`
The `.csv` file is in a subfolder within the folder where `index.html` resides ( like `./files/document.csv`)

So in short:

- Remove the upload function;
- place "path to file" in the index.html
- When index.html loads, it should load and process the files that is specified in the "path to file"

My guess would be that the code that needs to be altered would be this in index.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form">
        <input type=file id=files name=files[] class='btn'/>
        <output id=list></output>
```

Comment: use ajax instead of a file upload.

Comment: Thanks dandavis, any examples? Like i said...i'm not a big programmer, i use it so rarely that any training/course wold be overkill at the moment....so i need a bit more info.

Comment: In adition: maybe even "better": I have about 4 files i want to use.
I'm thinking of a dropdown instead of the manual upload so the user can select what file he wants to view.
Something like:
[code]
<select>
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a file</option>
    <option value="./files/file1.csv">File 1</option>
    <option value="./files/file2.csv">File 2</option>
</select>
[/code]
But how to "send" this to the JS function?

Comment: <select onchange=load(this.value)> where load(url) calls a new ajax object with the passed url and then displays the CSV data. Any ajax text file tutorial can get you code to turn into load().

Comment: Thanks, i got it loaded with this code:

`code: 
function ajax(a,b,c){//url,function,just a placeholder
 c=new XMLHttpRequest;
 c.open('GET',a);
 c.onload=b;
 c.send()
}

function alertTxt(){
 alert(this.response)
}

window.onload=function(){
 ajax('bad.csv')
}
`
But how to get this array to be picked up bij the csv.js script so it can be prossesed?

Comment: you call the csv.js's incoming function in the ajax callback. sadly, i've never used that, so i can't help further.

Comment: Thanks dandavis, So if i understand you correct, i have to make a change in csv.js so that it will be "listening" for the output from ajax???

Comment: more like you just use csv.js from inside the callback. eg: function(){ console.dir(CSV.parse(xhr.responseText)) }

Comment: thanks...but....ehmmm (remember...newbie ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered in comments, Here's a snippet:

Thanks, i got it loaded with this code: code:  `function ajax(a,b,c){//url,function,just a placeholder  c=new XMLHttpRequest;  c.open('GET',a);  c.onload=b;  c.send() }  function alertTxt(){  alert(this.response) }  window.onload=function(){  ajax('bad.csv') }`

Comment: Done....still missing a small thing...just cant remember how i fixed that... :-(